# Accessing hardware tables with structures in C using Linux on a x86 based platform

Tags: c, linux, drivers

I may not be searching the questiong correctly to find the right answers, so I'll describe what I am trying to do, but feel free to simply tell me what question I should be asking to find the answer.

I have a hardware device that has a chunk of memory in it.  Every 16 bytes in the memory represents an entry to HW based linked controller.  And I have enough memory for many-many entries.

I would like to represent each entry with a structure as shown below.

```
struct entry_desc {
    /* Address  */
    uint64_t addr;
    /* Length. */
    uint32_t len;
    /* Some flags. */
    uint16_t flags;
    /* Next pointer */
    uint16_t next;
};
```

Is there any guarantee that the order I have defined elements in my structure will map to memory in the same order?

Assuming little-endienness, I believe that "addr" will be placed in the lowest memory addresses between bytes 0 and 7 with the LSB of "addr" in memory offset 0 and the MSB of "addr" in memory offset 7.    Is that correct?  Wondering if it is true in some compilers and not in others.

Comment: C guarantees order of struct members, but it says nothing about sizes/alignment. And it allows arbitrary padding after each struct member.

Comment: There *are* some language compiler-specific extensions controlling the padding and/or alignment you can use. Otherwise you might want to use static asserts to check the actual placement against the desired one.

Answer (score 0):

In C, the order of the items in a struct does matter. Little endienness simply would refer to the order bytes are arranged for specific values/variables in memory. In your machine's memory, the locations for your variables will be in the same order as listed in your struct definition.

As far as padding goes, you can find details on how that works, and why order matters, [here](http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing/#_padding)

Also you may want to consider using `typedef` on structs.  It makes coding in the rest of the program a bit less of a hassle.

no typedef:

```
//always have to type "struct"
struct entry_desc* x= (struct entry_desc)malloc(sizeof(struct entry_desc)*blah);
```

with typedef in your struct definition:

```
typedef struct entry_desc {
    /* Address  */
    uint64_t addr;
    /* Length. */
    uint32_t len;
    /* Some flags. */
    uint16_t flags;
    /* Next pointer */
    uint16_t next;
}entry;
```

`entry* x =(entry)malloc(sizeof(entry)*blah)`

Comment: It has a very little to do with the question.  Just the link, perhaps..